# @Autowired is getting failed in Test classes when I migrate to Java11 from Java8. Getting UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired, spring-test

Tests run fine with Java 8. But As soon as I changes the runtime to JDK11, suddenly @Autowired doesn't work.
I'm getting the below exception when I do so.

```
04:44:41.427 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception 
while allowing TestExecutionListener 
[org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@4fce136b] to 
prepare test instance [com.dummy.SomeListener@4aa83f4f]
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.dummy.SomeTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'depRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dummy.DummyRepositoryImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1377) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:396) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119) ~[spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89) [.cp/:?]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) [.cp/:?]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542) [.cp/:?]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770) [.cp/:?]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464) [.cp/:?]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210) [.cp/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dummy.DummyRepositoryImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1648) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
```

And this is the example test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:/spring/test-context.xml"})
public class SomeTest {

   @Autowired
   DummyRepositoryImpl dummyRepo;

   @Test
   public void letsTest() {
       //Some code that uses dummyRepo
   }
}
```

For you reference, I'm including test related dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.27.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and plugins

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MetaspaceSize=1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m ${surefireArgLine} -enableassertions</argLine> 
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies> 
        </plugin>
```

Reference Project Structure I've
[image]

I've been spending lot of time but unable to understand what's happening here

Comment: `No qualifying bean of type 'com.dummy.DummyRepositoryImpl' available` -- the dependency that's missing is a ***Spring*** dependency, not a Maven dependency.  Have you provided the necessary dummy implementation?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes I did.

Comment: @JimGarrison And it's working in JDK8 but not on JDK11. Here is where I'm having little trouble to understand. It looks like dependency problem. But it should be there in JDK8 too but it runs fine in there.

Comment: It sounds like it might be a visibility issue with the Java module system. What happens if you launch the JVM with `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED`?